# KnockoutJS and AG-Grid Sample

Tags: knockout.js, ag-grid

I have been trying to understand combination of ag-grid and knockout about how they work.

I searched a lot but couldnt find any best example. So thought to ask question here whether Is there any documentation available for `knockout js` and `AG-Grid` ?

I have created sample but it is not working for Observable `rowData`: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dcd0arj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any official documentation about integration with Knockout JS, but here's how you could fix the problem of adding new row.

Essentially when you are adding new rows to the `this.rowData` observable, it is not necessarily pushed into the grid. So you need to call `gridOptions.api.setRowData` so that the grid is updated to display the new dataset. Here's the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0) for that. Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dcd0arj/5/) for that.

```
this.addRow = function() {
   this.rowData.push({
      make: "Toyota",
      model: "Celica",
      price: 35000
   });

   self.gridOptions().api.setRowData(self.rowData());
}
```

If you wanted to improve it a little, you could subscribe to changes on `this.rowData`, and call `gridOptions.api.setRowData` through the subscribe event handler. Like this:

```
self.rowData.subscribe(function(newValue){
    self.gridOptions().api.setRowData(newValue);
});
```

Here's the updated fiddle for subscribe event based logic: https://jsfiddle.net/2dcd0arj/6/

### Update

I just realized that there is an [update API](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#gsc.tab=0) for this as well. It allows you to add/update/remove rows without having to set the dataset again. Basically, you need to provide the object of the new row being added to the `gridOptions.api.updateRowData` function. Here's how your `addRow` function needs to be updated for this. Here's the link to [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2dcd0arj/7/).

```
self.addRow = function() {
    var newRow = {
      make: "Toyota",
      model: "Celica",
      price: 35000
    };

    self.rowData.push(newRow);
    var res = self.gridOptions().api.updateRowData({add: [newRow]});
    console.log("New row added: ", res);
};
```

You could take it a step further and [create a component](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) or a [binding handler](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for this.

Comment: Agreed. But for example, If I need to create component in Knockout and make everything observable like `cellEditor`, `cellRenderer` then this will not be possible I guess.

Comment: @user2988458 Making a component to support all the events supports by ag-grid would be quite tedious. You might rather want to check with the developers to see if they intend to develop one. Or, you could go on building the component as you need various feature.